# Storing Complex JS Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I've come across a situation where I need to store complex objects in `Node` for later use and instantiation of authentication objects for a third-party API.

The object is of this rough structure:

```
{
  _descriptors: { stream: { streamingDetectIntent: [Object] } },
  auth: 
   Auth {
     authClientPromise: Promise { [Object] },
     authClient: 
      JWT {
        transporter: DefaultTransporter {},
        _certificateCache: null,
        _certificateExpiry: null,
        _clientId: undefined,
        _clientSecret: undefined,
        _redirectUri: undefined,
        _opts: {},
        credentials: [Object],
        email: '<EMAIL>',
        keyFile: undefined,
        key: '<RSA KEY>',
        scopes: [Object],
        subject: undefined,
        gToken: [Function: GoogleToken],
        projectId: '<ID>',
        gtoken: [Object] },
     googleAuthClient: 
      GoogleAuth {
        _isGCE: undefined,
        jsonContent: [Object],
        cachedCredential: [Object],
        JWTClient: [Function: JWT],
        ComputeClient: [Object],
        IAMAuth: [Function: IAMAuth],
        Compute: [Object],
        JWT: [Function: JWT],
        JWTAccess: [Function: JWTAccess],
        OAuth2: [Object],
        UserRefreshClient: [Function: UserRefreshClient],
        _cachedProjectId: '<ID>' },
     config: 
      { clientConfig: {},
        port: 443,
        scopes: [Object] },
     credentials: null,
     environment: {},
     projectId: '<ID>' },
  _pathTemplates: { sessionPathTemplate: projects/{project=*}/agent/sessions/{session=*} },
  _innerApiCalls: 
   { detectIntent: [Function: apiCallInner],
     streamingDetectIntent: [Function: apiCallInner] } }
```

As you can see, the object contains other necessary objects, but more importantly, it has *functions* and *promises* in it that need to be preserved.

My first idea was to simply encrypt the entire stringified object and decrypt and parse back into `JSON` when I needed it, but that didn't preserve the `Promises` or functions that are in the object.

Is there a method of temporarily storing this type of object for later use, or in a method that can persist across different application if sent back and forth?

Comment: Data needs to be "serialized" to be sent over a network or stored. JavaScript typically does this using JSON. Since this object contains complex data (functions), it's up to your code to turn it into a string, and then turn that string (deserialize) back into complex objects.

Comment: Functions can actually be turned into a string (`myFunc.toString()`), which preserves their internal code. But since functions usually reference variables from outside of the function body, this is very unreliable.

Comment: It's not clear from your description why you need to store the functions and promises rather than just the values.  My instincts say this is a poor design, but there's not enough information to help you decouple it.

Comment: @Paul this is a sample payload for an authentication object that is being generated, stored, and reused on an hourly basis by an AWS lambda and being sent to the application using it to reset the authenication object with this saved payload to avoid the time expensive process of regenerating it for every request as the api does

Comment: I imagine you'll have a problem with the promises, as they execute the asynchronous call on creation, which you may not want.

Comment: Restoring JavaScript that actually runs could be risky as if the data source ever becomes compromised it could cause security issues in your app.  I would recommend taking the JSON route and then after the data has been restored to reinstate any Promises separately.

Comment: @m_callens that still sounds all like things that can be generated from storing just the data.